# How to pass values to a recursive call involving file.io

Tags: python

So recently I was working on a file.io recursive homework involving basic os methods and I have run into an error where the values in one part of the recursive function are not being passed on when I call the function again.

```
def findLargestFile(path):
    findLargestFileHelper(path)


def findLargestFileHelper(path, size=0, pathToLargest=""):
    if (os.path.isdir(path) == False):
        if os.path.getsize(path) > size:
            size = os.path.getsize(path)
            pathToLargest = print(path)
    else:
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            findLargestFileHelper(path + "/" + filename, size, pathToLargest)
    
    return pathToLargest
```

What I am trying to do is find the largest file in a folder, by recursively looping through all the folders till I find a file, and seeing if that is the largest file and if it is, pass the size in to "size" and pass the path to the file to "pathToLargest".

It seems that size is not passed in the else statement, and also when I just pass "path" to pathToLargest, it also is not working. (Pretty sure print(path) isn't the way to go about it either)

If someone could suggest what I should do instead, that would be greatly appreciated.